# Can someone help me with this formula ? (Standard deviation)

Tags: math, formula

So I just started to learn Java, but my prof. just gave us this wild formula which we have to translate into code. I can't figure it out how to make this possible, can someone help me ?

σ means Standard deviation
µ means average
x means The Array x
N means N variables

[image: Formula]]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Where are you getting stuck with translating that formula? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The `Σ` upper-case Sigma character simply means the sum of.

So, for every data value, subtract the mean (average, in layman's terms) and square the result. Add all of those values together, divide it by the number of data values minus one, then take the square root of that.

Psuedo-code for that would be something like below. First, a function for calculating mean:

```
def calcMean(collection):
    # Initialise for working out mean (sum / count).

    sum = 0, count = 0

    # Add every item to the sum and keep count.

    for item in collection:
        sum = sum + item
        count = count + 1

    # Avoid dive by zero, you choose what to do.

    if count == 0:
        handle empty collection somehow

    # Return the mean.

    return sum / count
```

Then using that to calculate the standard deviation:

```
def calcStdDev(collection):
    # Get mean of the collection, initialise accumulator and count.

    mean = calcMean(collection)
    accum = 0, count = 0
    for item in collection:
        # Accumulate each '(item-mean) squared' value.

        diff = item - mean
        accum = accum + diff * diff

    # Avoid dive by zero, you choose what to do.

    if count < 2:
        handle too-small collection somehow

    # Divide and square root for result.

    return sqrt(sum / (count - 1))
```

Now your job is to turn that pseudo-code into Java, something that should be a bit easier than turning the *formula* into Java.